# how to search and replace PATH element with SED of xml file in bash

Tags: bash, sed, xml

I would like to replace the current element inside example path tag from:

```
...
<examples>
<example path='/test/test123/test12345.txt'/>
<examples>
...
```

to

```
...
<examples>
<example path=/test/test123/>
<examples>
...
```

with

`sed -i 's/<example path=\/test\/test123\/test12345.txt'>/<example path=\/test\/test123\/>' 123.xml`

but it says:

`-bash: example: No such file or directory`

Comment: You didnot set a "sed command". To correct it you have to write: `sed -i s/'escaped-string'/'target-string'/ filename.xml`

Comment: Your target `<example path=/test/test123/>` is either wrong (it is) or ambiguous. Either it's an unclosed element `<example path="/test/test123/">` with no closing `<element/>` shown, or it's a singleton `<example path="/test/test123"/>`. This is why quoting values is necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because of mismatched single quotes.

The quoted string ends at the second quote. The shell finds unquoted `>/<example` and interprets this as redirection.

Additionally your `sed` command is incomplete. The trailing separator `/` is missing.

I also fixed the `sed` commands to match the input data which has been edited.

If you want to have single quotes inside the `sed` command you have to either use double quotes around the command and make sure there is nothing inside the double quotes that would get expanded by the shell

```
sed -i "s/<example path='\/test\/test123\/test12345.txt'\/>/<example path=\/test\/test123\/>/" 123.xml
```

or use escaped single quotes like this

```
sed -i 's/<example path='\''\/test\/test123\/test12345.txt'\''\/>/<example path=\/test\/test123\/>/' 123.xml
```

BTW: If you use a different separator character (not slash `/`) you don't need to escape the slashes in the pattern or replacement, e.g.

```
sed -i "s#<example path='/test/test123/test12345.txt'/>#<example path=/test/test123/>#" 123.xml
sed -i 's#<example path='\''/test/test123/test12345.txt'\''/>#<example path=/test/test123/>#' 123.xml
```

Your desired output as shown in the question is not valid XML. Attributes must be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an XML editor to edit XML. It can handle changes to the layout of the XML schema within the file, unexpected comments, etc. My preferred one is `xmlstarlet`

Example file, `x.xml`

```
<root>
  <examples/>
  <example path='/test/test123/test12345.txt'/>
  <examples/>
</root>
```

Command, which updates the attribute `path` in any element `example` to the value `/test/test123`

```
xmlstarlet ed --update '//example/@path' --value '/test/test123' x.xml
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <examples/>
  <example path="/test/test123"/>
  <examples/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i -e s/test\///g 123.xml`  to just delete,
`sed -i -e s/test\//replacement/g 123.xml`  to replace with something

Comment: While that answer describes the general usage of `sed`, it does not deal with the particular challenges of editing structured text (like XML or JSON) which is the key problem here.

Comment: Also, it is recommeded to always quote your `sed` expressions to prevent unwanted behaviour (as we have seen in the OPs problem).

Comment: @AdminBee, there is no modification of the xml structure needed, but the content.

Comment: That is not quite the point. Structured text is characterized by having to locate the content to be being modified within possible nested layers of start/end tags, many of which look similar in pattern and only differ by additional attributes that need to be taken into account. They are also usually spread out over several lines and are not easily accessible by the "single-line" search you describe - consider the case that the `test/test123` path does not only occur in `<examples><example path= ../.></example>`, but also in `<config><cfgfile path= .../></config>` where no change should occur.