# Replace PATH element with SED of multiple xml file in bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I have managed to replace 1 xml file. However, I have 10 of them from `test1.xml` to `test30.xml` and they have different Paths at the end:

- `test1.xml`

  ```
  ...
  <examples>
  <example path='/test/test123/st1.txt'/>
  <examples>
  ...
  ```
- `test2.xml`

  ```
  ...
  <examples>
  <example path='/test/test123/te2.txt'/>
  <examples>
  ...
  ```

etc. until

- `test30.xml`

  ```
  ...
  <examples>
  <example path='/test/test123/removethispart.txt'/>
  <examples>
  ...
  ```

**The output** should look like this:

````
```
...
<examples>
<example path='/test/test123/'/>
<examples>
...
```
````

Previously, I used this and it can change one file

```
sed -i "s#<example path='/test/test123/st1.txt'/>#<example path=/test/test123/>#" test1.xml
```

However, I would like to change multiple files at once and the below script executed but upon `cat` the xml file, it did not show the changes

```
sed -i "s#<example path='/test/test123/*.txt'/>#<example path='/test/test123/'>#" *.xml
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please [don't ask the same question twice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/610016/100397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the problem is that you use "shell glob" (a.k.a "wildcard") patterns where a regular expression pattern is needed.

The part `/test/test123/*.txt` actually means "`/test/test123`, followed by zero or more `/` characters, followed by any single character, followed by `txt`".

This pattern is not what you want, and nowhere in your files.

Instead, what you need is `/test/test123/[^.]*\.txt`, meaning "`/test/test123/`, followed by any number of characters that are *not* the `.` (refer to "greedy regular expressions" on why this is necessary), followed by *a literal `.`*, followed by `txt`".

The complete command would then look like

```
sed -i "s#<example path='/test/test123/[^.]*\.txt'/>#<example path='/test/test123/'>#" *.xml
```

**Note**

If your filenames can contain `.` besides the `.txt` extension, the above will not work correctly. In that case, use

```
sed -i "s#<example path='/test/test123/.*\.txt'/>#<example path='/test/test123/'>#" *.xml
```

meaning "`/test/test123/`, followed by zero or more characters of any kind, followed by a literal `.`, followed by `txt`". This will work correctly unless the `.txt` pattern can occurr again later on the line (which should not be the case for your input).

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i "s#<example path='/test/test123/.*\.txt'/>#<example path='/test/test123/'>#" *.xml`

This solves my problem. Cheers all! :)

Comment: You do not need to replicate AdminBee's answer. Marking it as accepted, as you have done, is enough to convey the message that it works!